# Proper testing of GenServer and Supervisor

Tags: elixir

I'm pretty new to implementing Genserver within Elixir. I have a case where I'm trying to manage some state and Genserver is working great for this case. But, I'm running into some complications when it comes to testing the Genserver.

I have two tests that seem to be bumping into each other. I have a unit level test for my Genserver and a higher level test where the function I call is using the Genserver with the module. Here are my two test cases:

#### FIRST:

```
defmodule MyApp.ScoreTableQueueTest do
  use MyApp.DataCase

  alias MyApp.{ScoreTableQueue}

  setup do
    start_supervised(ScoreTableQueue)
    :ok
  end

  test "pushes value in the queue" do
    assert :ok == ScoreTableQueue.push([1,2,3,4])
  end

  test "pops the full value of the queue" do
    assert [[1,2,3,4]] == ScoreTableQueue.pop()
  end
end
```

If I run this in isolation it passes everytime. But If I run this test it will periodically break:

#### SECOND:

```
  setup do
    start_supervised(ScoreTableQueue)
    :ok
  end

  describe "distribute" do
    test "it distrbutes the correct season points" do
      {:ok, table} = List.first(MyApp.ScoreTableAllocator.distribute())

      assert table.table_details.information == [
               %{team_id: team_3.id, team_score: "N/A"},
               %{team_id: team_2.id, team_score: ps_2.score},
               %{team_id: team_1.id, team_score: ps_1.score}
             ]

      assert table.question_id == question.id
      assert table.season_id == season.id
    end
  end
```

Within my `distribute/1` function the Genserver actually gets used. If I call this test in isolation it works fine everytime. But when I run the tests together it seems to break half the time leading me to believe that I'm starting the same server and passing information to the same server between tests.

My question: How do I separate each test from each other? I want each test to have a completely different server for each case, at least each file. What is the Elixir way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would propose in this case is to modify the module's API functions to accept the server to use, defaulting to the global instance. Something along these lines:

```
defmodule MyApp.ScoreTableQueue do
  use GenServer

  def push(server \\ __MODULE__, item) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:push, item})
  end

  ...
end
```

Then in your tests you simply start an instance per test:

```
setup do
  {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(MyApp.ScoreTableQueue, _init_args = nil)
  {:ok, queue: pid}
end

test "pushes value in the queue", %{queue: queue} do
  assert :ok == ScoreTableQueue.push(queue, [1,2,3,4])
end
```

When you start using `start_supervised` it's started according to the `child_spec` function in your module - I assume it specifies the global instance of your server, so it's very possible for the two tests to interfere with each other.

Another option would be to set the tests to synchronous (by using `use MyApp.DataCase, async: false`), so that they are never ran concurrently. This might be even simpler, although perhaps a little slower if your test suite is large.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just had one question. I tried `MyApp.DataCase, async: false` but it didn't seem to fix the problem. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're not using the passed `queue` variable in your test @paweł-obrok. Also as general feedback, I don't think tests should depend on each other. For example, "pops the full value of the queue" fails if run all alone. Maybe setup the queue in each test with the required state to operate on it?

Comment: "You're not using the passed queue variable in your test @paweł-obrok. Also as general feedback, I don't think tests should depend on each other."

You're right, fixed.

Comment: "Also as general feedback, I don't think tests should depend on each other. For example, "pops the full value of the queue" fails if run all alone. Maybe setup the queue in each test with the required state to operate on it?"

I agree, of course. Setting up the full state is much easier when creating a new GenServer for each test like in the first part. What I suspect is happening, even with `async: false` is that some tests are leaving the server in a non-clean state. I haven't used `start_supervised` that much, so can't be really sure.